# DroidGap cannot be resolved into a type

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

hi i am getting an error that DroidGap cannot be resolved as a type 
my code is

```
package com.hello.ponegap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.hello.*;

public class HelloponegapActivity extends DroidGap  {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

  @Override  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
     super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  }
}
```

thanks in advance 
also i am not getting build path when i right click on lib

Comment: you have missed the import, also call `super.onCreate()` before calling `super.loadUrl()`

Comment: i even tried to call super. onCreate()  before calling super.loadUrl()
but its no use

Comment: this is very basic application using phonegap - https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/tree/master/android-cordova-lawnchair

Comment: its not for any specific use in this case but that is the correct placement for the `onCreate()` method call

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to the imports

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
```

---

EDIT:

If you are using Eclipse, you can use the key combination `Ctrl + Shift + O` to organize imports. This removes unused imports, and also will import the needed packages and/or classes (If there are multiple possibilities, e.g. `android.view.View.OnClickListener` and `android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, Eclipse will give you the chance to select the desired class to import).

---

EDIT:

You did not add the cordova jar to the build path. I checked your `.classpath` file on the github repo, and it lacks this line: `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/cordova-1.8.1.jar"/>`.

**Solution:** Right-click on the `codova-1.x.x.jar` -> Build path -> Add to build path.

Please try to follow the steps defined [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android).

---

EDIT

Do the following: 1. Right-click the project. 2. Click properties. 3. On the left, select Java Build Path. 4. You see four tabs: `Source`, `Projects`, `Libraries`, `Order and Export`. Select `Libraries`. 5. On the right click the button `Add JARs...`. 6. Search for `cordova-1.x.x.jar` in your project, and select it. 7. Click `OK`. 8. Done

Comment: My app force closes once i run it

Comment: Give me a stacktrace, and I'll give you the solution.

Comment: man , when i right click codova-1.x.x.jar , i am not getting any Build path option

Comment: i have added some pics check tat

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3885309305393&set=a.1177349648094.26618.1658705429&type=1&theater

Comment: sorry to say, but the relevant part of the `logcat` is not visible.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3885316945584&set=a.1177349648094.26618.1658705429&type=1&theater

Comment: yes i saw , logcat
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3885324625776&set=a.1177349648094.26618.1658705429&type=1&theater

Comment: try to rename the directory `lib` to `libs`

Comment: when i rename the folder to libs its showing you project contains error

Comment: man, just create a new project, and follow the steps EXACTLY as described here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Comment: well i downloaded cordova-1.8.1.jar , does this have any thing to do

Comment: Not at all. You just messed up adding the .jar to the build path. First you should remove the .jar from the build path, then rename the lib directory to libs, then add the .jar file to the build path as I described it above. Is it that hard?

Comment: how to do this step
Verify that cordova-1.8.0.jar is listed in the Build Path for your project. Right click on the /libs folder and go to Build Paths/ > Configure Build Path.... Then, in the Libraries tab, add cordova-1.8.0.jar to the project. If Eclipse is being temperamental, you might need to refresh (F5) the project once again.

Comment: wow i got it the thing is i didnt add some requisite file , thanks buddy.

Comment: well,
ou did not add the cordova jar to the build path. I checked your .classpath file on the github repo, and it lacks this line: <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/cordova-1.8.1.jar"/>.
so u mean my code is visible in github

Comment: sorry, that was dhaval's project

Answer (score 1):

**Eclpise:**
This might be stupid, but if you added the cordova jar and the app is STILL not working on your emulator or device, check that you have also checked the checkbox left of the jar file in

"Project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export"

Comment: this is yet another step towards solving the issue

Comment: The tick box in the Order and Export only indicates that a particular library should be exported as part of the classpath into another project that uses the current one in its build path, so unlikely to be an issue in this case.