# The import android.app.DroidGap cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

God, this gives me headaches. I checked everything according this post [DroidGap cannot be resolved into a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242697/droidgap-cannot-be-resolved-into-a-type) and it still doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.app.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;


public class SpotableActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_spotable, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I've got cordova jar in my build path.

I followed all the steps from docs over here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps in the page you cite do not have `android.app.DroidGap`, because there is no such class AFAIK. `DroidGap`, according to that page, is in `org.apache.cordova`.

So, delete the `DroidGap` `import` statement, and you should have better luck.

Comment: Thanks, it loaded up, but the cordova isn't working.. Even the jquery doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For Cordova 2.0.0 you do not need the line:

```
android.app.DroidGap;
```

The documentation appears to be incorrect in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cordova.2.9.1.jar, make sure you replace it with the cordova.2.9.0.jar, then .. magic ..

Don't forget to :
1. Right click cordova.2.9.0.jar >> Build Path >> Add to Build Path
2. Right click cordova.2.9.0.jar >> Build Path >> Configure Build Path >> Order and Export >> Check the cordova-2.9.0.jar >> OK
3. Add this code to AndroidManifest.xml, above the 'uses-sdk ... ...' code

```
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```

4. At *yourcode*.java, try to remove this code

   ```
   import android.app.DroidGap;
   ```

and maybe this code too

```
     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_spotable, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Run it.
It worked for me after 4 hours in headache mode.