# DroidGap cannot be resolved Compilation error

Tags: android

I am trying to do a small HelloWorld Application using PhoneGap and Android  ??
I have downloaded phonegap-2.9.1 and copied cordova.2.9.0.jar to the libs folder

I am getting Compilation error at The import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap cannot be resolved

```
package com.example.helloworld;


import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
    public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {


    }
```

Compilation error DroidGap cannot be resolved

This is the screen shot of the compilation error

[image]

Could anybody please help me resolving this .

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the jar to your build path?

Right click on your jar, go to `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path...`

In the `Libraries` tab, click `Add JARs...` and select your jar.

Then, in the `Order and Export` tab, make sure that your jar is checked.

That's it - it should now work!

Here's another thread on a similar issue: [DroidGap cannot be resolved into a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242697/droidgap-cannot-be-resolved-into-a-type?rq=1)