# Extends error in Phonegap2.9.1

Tags: android, cordova

I have phonegap-2.9.1 downloaded from phonegap.com

I have eclipse Android Developer Tools ( Build: v22.0.5-757759 )

There i make new project and create folder inside assets/www and put cordova.js files from phonegap-2.9.1 folder and i put cordova.2.9.0.jar file libs folder and i built path and configure to adding cordova.2.9.0.jar files and put xml folder in res folder with config.xml file.

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap
{   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Error is DroidGap cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [DroidGap cannot be resolved into a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242697/droidgap-cannot-be-resolved-into-a-type) ?

Comment: import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

It is also give an error
"import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;" cannot be resolved.

Comment: did you try everything in both answers to that question?

Comment: Yes i tried.
import org.apache.cordova.*;
After cordova all classes assessible like camera,api,battery,capture but DroidGap is not there

Comment: I solve the problem but i have question phonegap say develop for one and get all apps for other os but how.? Where i have to develop and how to export? From eclipse we can exports other os apps?

Comment: If you solved the problem, please answer your own question so that others with the same issue can find help.

Re: other OS: No, you cannot build for iOS (for instance) from Eclipse. You must use a Mac and XCode and sign up for a developer account with Apple.